# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "EXIST": syntax error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

When i create a database in python appear the syntax error:

```
  File "C:\Users\CARLO\Desktop\esercizi python\programma trivium\backend.py", line 7, in connect
    curs.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, categoria text, titolo text, autore text, "
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "EXIST": syntax error
```

i don't understand because in all the explanation the code is like this

```
import sqlite3

def connect():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('libri.db')
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, categoria text, titolo text, autore text, "
                 "anno integer, volume integer")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: You're missing an S from EXISTS - `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`

Comment: can you write the correct string?

Comment: @CarloPiraino,   the error has been corrected.  you were missing and `S` from `exists`.

Answer (score 1):

There were two factors:

1. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST` -> `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`  (missing `S`)
2. the query string was broken into 2 strings.

So this should work (and be a bit clearer):

```py
import sqlite3

def connect():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('libri.db')
    curs = conn.cursor()
    query_string = """ 
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book 
        (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
        categoria text, 
        titolo text, 
        autore text, 
        anno integer, 
        volume integer)
        """
    curs.execute(query_string)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

connect()
```